# Add nested object params in UPDATE

Tags: mysql, json

I'm having a json format stored in the database like this

```
{"fooKey": "fooValue", "barKey": "barValue"}
```

I'm trying to run an UPDATE query using JSON_SET in order to add some additional stuff, so

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `dbcol` = JSON_SET(`dbcol`, '$.newitem', 'newvalue')
WHERE `id` = 12;
```

The problem is I want to add some nested elements so my final result should look like this

```
{"fooKey":"fooValue","barKey":"barValue", "newItem":"newValue", "anotherNewItem":{"subItemKey":"subItemValue", "anotherSubItemKey":"anotherSubItemValue"}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example you have given, you can nest two [`JSON_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) calls, and use [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to create the data to be inserted for key `anothernewitem`:

```
UPDATE table
SET dbcol = JSON_SET(JSON_SET(dbcol, '$.newitem', 'newvalue'),
                     '$.anothernewitem', 
                     JSON_OBJECT('subitemkey', 'subitemvalue', 'anothersubitemkey', 'anothersubitemvalue'))
WHERE id = 12;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wVJ2kQfs6v6DjstQeZJLBa/0)